# Error: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference raised from `executeElementAnimation`

Tags: javascript, windows, html

I'm making a win8 app and running into the following error:

```
{"exception":null,
 "error":
    [{"description":"Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference",
    "number":-2146823281,
    "stack":"TypeError: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference\n
       at executeElementAnimation (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:6652:13)\n
       at applyAction (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:6754:25)\n
       at executeAnimation (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:6815:13)\n
       at enterPage (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/ui.js:1473:9)\n
       at navigated (ms-appx://fa541b49-1aef-4f6c-9002-7d2e2fcadc25/js/navigator.js:114:21)\n
       at parentElement (ms-appx://fa541b49-1aef-4f6c-9002-7d2e2fcadc25/js/navigator.js:94:29)\n
       at notifySuccess (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1404:21)\n
       at enter (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1091:21)\n
       at _run (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1307:17)\n
       at _completed (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1275:13)"},
    {"description":"Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference","number":-2146823281,
    "stack":"TypeError: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference\n
       at executeElementTransition (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:6575:13)\n
       at applyAction (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:6754:25)\n
       at executeTransition (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:6837:13)\n
       at enterPage (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/ui.js:1484:9)\n
       at navigated (ms-appx://fa541b49-1aef-4f6c-9002-7d2e2fcadc25/js/navigator.js:114:21)\n
       at parentElement (ms-appx://fa541b49-1aef-4f6c-9002-7d2e2fcadc25/js/navigator.js:94:29)\n
       at notifySuccess (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1404:21)\n
       at enter (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1091:21)\n
       at _run (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1307:17)\n
       at _completed (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1275:13)"}],
    "promise":{"_oncancel":null,
    "_nextState":null,
    "_state":{"name":"error","done":null,"then":null},
    "_value":
    [{"description":"Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference",
    "number":-2146823281,
    "stack":"TypeError: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference\n
       at executeElementAnimation (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:6652:13)\n
       at applyAction (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:6754:25)\n
       at executeAnimation (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:6815:13)\n
       at enterPage (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/ui.js:1473:9)\n
       at navigated (ms-appx://fa541b49-1aef-4f6c-9002-7d2e2fcadc25/js/navigator.js:114:21)\n
       at parentElement (ms-appx://fa541b49-1aef-4f6c-9002-7d2e2fcadc25/js/navigator.js:94:29)\n
       at notifySuccess (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1404:21)\n
       at enter (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1091:21)\n
       at _run (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1307:17)\n
       at _completed (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1275:13)"},
    {"description":"Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference",
    "number":-2146823281,
    "stack":"TypeError: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference\n
       at executeElementTransition (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:6575:13)\n
       at applyAction (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:6754:25)\n
       at executeTransition (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:6837:13)\n
       at enterPage (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/ui.js:1484:9)\n
       at navigated (ms-appx://fa541b49-1aef-4f6c-9002-7d2e2fcadc25/js/navigator.js:114:21)\n
       at parentElement (ms-appx://fa541b49-1aef-4f6c-9002-7d2e2fcadc25/js/navigator.js:94:29)\n
       at notifySuccess (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1404:21)\n
       at enter (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1091:21)\n
       at _run (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1307:17)\n
       at _completed (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:1275:13)"}],"_isException":false,"_errorId":4},"id":4}
```

My javascript file is:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var ui = WinJS.UI;
var utils = WinJS.Utilities;

ui.Pages.define("/pages/itemDetail/itemDetail.html", {

    // Template tutorial code
    getAnimationElements: function () {
        return [[this.element.querySelector("header")], [this.element.querySelector(".content")]];
    },

    // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
    // populates the page elements with the app's data.
    ready: function (element, options) {
        var item = options && options.item ? Data.resolveItemReference(options.item) : Data.items.getAt(0);
        element.querySelector(".titlearea .pagetitle").textContent = item.group.title;
        //element.querySelector("article .item-title").textContent = item.title;
        //element.querySelector("article .item-subtitle").textContent = item.subtitle;
        //element.querySelector("article .item-image").src = item.backgroundImage;
        //element.querySelector("article .item-image").alt = item.subtitle;
        //element.querySelector("article .item-content").innerHTML = item.content;

        //element.querySelector(".detailfontstyle").textContent = item.mIOs.PrimaryObjective;



        // Template tutorial code
        appbar.winControl.disabled = false;
        appbar.winControl.hideCommands([labelSize, markItem]);
        appbar.winControl.showCommands([textSize]);
    },

    // Template tutorial code
    setPageFocus: function () {
        this.element.querySelector(".content").focus();
    },
});
})();
```

and HTML file is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>itemDetailPage</title>

<!-- WinJS references -->
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/pages/MarketIODetails/marketingIODetails.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/pages/itemDetail/itemDetail.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/data.js"></script>
<script src="/pages/itemDetail/itemDetail.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- The content that will be loaded and displayed. -->
<div class="itemdetailpage fragment">
    <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
        <button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled></button>
        <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
            <span class="pagetitle"></span>
        </h1>
    </header>
    <div class="details">
    <h1 style="font-family:'segoe ui'; color:orange;text-align:center; margin-     bottom:20px">Details</h1>
    <!--<h2 class="detailfontstyle">Primary obj: Put primary obj here</h2>-->
    <!--<h2 class="detailfontstyle org">Org: Put organisation here</h2>
    <h2 class="detailfontstyle sap">SAP IO: Put SAP IO here</h2>
    <h2 class="detailfontstyle editor1">Editor 1: Put editor name here</h2>
    <h2 class="detailfontstyle edito2">Editor 2: Put editor name here</h2>-->

</div>
<div class="tablecontainer">
    <div class="tableoutlay">
            <h1 style="font-family:'segoe ui'; color:orange; text-align:center">Budget Table</h1>
            <table class="forecastTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="height: 5px">
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Available</th>
                        <th>Assigned</th>
                        <th>Unassigned</th>
                        <th>Approved</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Vendor</th>
                        <td>1231</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>7292</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>RevAdjust</th>
                        <td>1231</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>7292</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Market</th>
                        <td>1231</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>7292</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

<div class="tableoutlay" style="margin-top:43px">
    <h1 style="font-family: 'segoe ui'; color: orange; text-align:center">Forecast Table</h1>
    <table class="forecastTable">
            <thead>
                    <tr style="height: 5px">
                        <th></th>
                        <th>July</th>
                        <th>Aug</th>
                        <th>Sep</th>
                        <th>Oct</th>
                        <th>Nove</th>
                        <th>Dec</th>
                        <th>Jan</th>
                        <th>Feb</th>
                        <th>Mar</th>
                        <th>Apr</th>
                        <th>May</th>
                        <th>June</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Vendor</th>
                        <td>1231</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>7292</td>
                        <td>9821</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>7292</td>
                        <td>9821</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>1289</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Budget</th>
                        <td>1231</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>7292</td>
                        <td>9821</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>7292</td>
                        <td>9821</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>1289</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Market</th>
                        <td>1231</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>7292</td>
                        <td>9821</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>7292</td>
                        <td>9821</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>1289</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Some</th>
                        <td>1231</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>7292</td>
                        <td>9821</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>7292</td>
                        <td>9821</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>1289</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Some</th>
                        <td>1231</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>7292</td>
                        <td>9821</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>7292</td>
                        <td>9821</td>
                        <td>4325</td>
                        <td>1278</td>
                        <td>1289</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>          
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Any ideas as to how to solve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: None of the code you have posted contains any attempt to access a `style` property. Meaning you're not showing us the right code.

Comment: The attempts to access style property is being done inside the WinJS library, in the base.js file in executeElementAnimation() function. I'm confused as to why that's causing a problem. That's what I've been able to narrow down till now.

Comment: Since the error is coming from `executeElementAnimation`, it means that you passed `null` or `undefined` when you should have passed an element for animation. Set a breakpoint on your `getAnimationElements` function and make sure it's not getting `null` back from its `querySelector` calls. In particular I don't see any element in your HTML with `CLASS="content"`.

Comment: Thanks RaymondChen, that's the answer.